# Cannot fetch data from JSON request although I know it's returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain

I'm trying to get a hold of the data returned from getJSON, but I just can't get it to work. I've tried the same code with the search.twitter API, and that works fine, but it doesn't work with the other site. I know that the data is returned cause I can find it when I use the Inspector. The values I find through the Inspector are:

```
[{"id":62093,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"It Will Follow The Rain"},{"id":62094,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Pistol Dreams"},{"id":62095,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Troubles Will Be Gone"},{"id":80523,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Love Is All"},{"id":80524,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"I Won't Be Found"},{"id":80525,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Where Do My Bluebird Fly"},{"id":80526,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Sparrow And The Medicine"},{"id":80527,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"Into The Stream"},{"id":81068,"type":"Song","artist":{"id":12382,"type":"Artist","nameWithoutThePrefix":"Tallest Man On Earth","useThePrefix":true,"name":"The Tallest Man On Earth"},"title":"The Blizzards Never Seen The Desert Sands"}]
```

So I know they are returned from the server.

and my js code is:

```
function searchSongsterrForTab(){
    var artist = "\"The Tallest Man On Earth\""
    var url = "http://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?callback=?&artists=" + artist;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried all sorts of different code, but I just can't seem to print the values.

All help are truly appreciated!

Comment: what `console.log(data)` says ?

Comment: it doesn't say anything. It never enters the success function. When I try with the search.twitter API it prints everything.

Comment: try console.log(data) just when it enters the success, not in the each loop. if you see it in the request response in the NET panel it should also appear there. the JSON reponse is valid

Comment: `console.log` is not writing anything because `success` is never called. If you define an error handler you will get a message that JSONP callback is not getting called -> service doesn't support JSONP. Twitter API supports JSONP so the `success` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `dataType` as `jsonp` but the service is just returning `json` which you cannot use crossdomain.

jQuery's error message is: `"jQuery1710014922410249710083_1323288745545 was not called"` which  means that the callback is not getting called as it should be.

### Update:

There is a way how you can retrieve the data even when the service doesn't support JSONP format. See [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) link for details.

My example is using **[jquery.xdomainajax.js](https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)** script which is routing the ajax request to [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) which is able to retrieve a *whole HTML page in a JSONP* format. So the example below is using normal HTML page to retrieve the data.

- Pros:

  - You are able to retrieve any HTML content.
  - It is very flexible as you are not depending what the webservice can get you.
- Cons:

  - It is slower, because you are using Yahoo service to process and fetch whole HTML data.
  - There is also more data transferred.

See **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/HyP4E/)** snippet for working example.

**Code:**

```
var artist = "The Tallest Man On Earth";

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.songsterr.com/a/wa/search?pattern=' + escape(artist),
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
    // see http://www.songsterr.com/a/wa/search?pattern=The%20Tallest%20Man%20On%20Earth
    // 1) res.responseText => get HTML of the page
    // 2) get odd anchors inside (it is zero-indexed) => get anchors containing song names
    // 3) map array of anchor elements into only their text => get song names
    var songs = $(res.responseText).find('div.song a:odd').map(function(i, el) { return $(el).text() });
    console.log(songs);
  }
});
```

This is just a demonstration. If you need any other data from the page then inspect structure of the page, retrieve it and process and shown in the example above.

Comment: I've tried both jsonp and json, but nothing works. Do you mean that this won't work at all, or is there another way around this? Sorry, but I've never worked with json before so I'm not very good at this.

Comment: @kentrh Yes, nothing works because they don't want you to use their service crossdomain. Only JSONP works crossdomain and they are not supporting it. But there is still way how to retrieve the data - see my big update :).

Comment: This worked like a charm! :) Thank you so much! Been struggling for days with this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're being hit by cross-domain violation? You can't just access any web service from a random web-page hosted by a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Songsterr doesn't support JSONP. Meaning, it doesn't wrap the data with your given callback function.