# Whois with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, whois

I want to be able to get whois data (and idn domains too) by client-side javascript. Is it possible? Maybe some free REST-like WhoIs service exists?

Comment: http://www.namepros.com/programming/50210-whois-script.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using http://whoisxmlapi.com service.

The service URL: http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService

You need to specify `outputFormat=json` and `domainName=insert_domain_here` parameters..

**Example URL**: http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?outputFormat=json&domainName=stackoverflow.com.

**Example code** (using jQuery to simplify AJAX communication):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    domainName: 'stackoverflow.com',
    outputFormat: 'json'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.WhoisRecord);
  }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/fHPcE/)** is the working code.

### Update:

The service mentioned above is not free, but there are several free whois services that are providing HTML output and by using YQL you can retrieve the HTML as a JS. See **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421801/cannot-fetch-data-from-json-request-although-i-know-its-returned/8421896#8421896)** answer for more details.

**Example** (using jQuery & [jquery.xdomainajax](https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)):

```
var domain = 'stackoverflow.com';
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://whois.webhosting.info/' + domain,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
    // using jQuery to find table with class "body_text" and appending it to a page
    $(res.responseText).find('table.body_text').appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/eXMMc/)** is the working code.

You need to have a look at the structure of the HTML document and select, process and display the data you are interested in. The example is just printing whole table without any processing.

Comment: thx! it looks very cool! but as I understand - this service allows only about 50 queries and if i want more I should pay for it. is it so? or maybe I have some misunderstanding.

Comment: @dizpers Yes, that service is not free. I suggested another alternative solution - see update of the answer :).

Comment: I created a similar service at http://www.robowhois.com/. We provide JSON output so that you can easily parse it with JavaScript.

Comment: @dizpers Please see my updated answer and if you have no more questions then accepted it.

Comment: What is the request limit of your last example?

Comment: @dizpers I used to use the great service by [robowhois](http://robowhois.com) but they are discontinued now so i switched to [this provider](https://jsonwhoisapi.com) instead, hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

What you can do if you have exec() enabled in php is create a php file with the following:

```
exec('whois domain.com');
```

and then create aa .ajax() request to the php script where you pass the domain name and output  it.

Comment: thx! but for some reasons I need to use queries only for remote servers.

Comment: Wrong advice. Do not shell out from PHP just to run a whois command. You have specific libraries inside of PHP to do whois queries or just open a TCP socket on port 43 this is enough, and read RFC3912 for details.

Answer (score 2):

An npm package called [node-whois](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-whois) did the job for me. It's server side JS, not client side, but perhaps this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

i'm also trying to find out a free whois provider with JSON output, couldn't find one. But, there are [WHOIS windows client provided by Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx) and like someone mentioned above, we can use PHP/cgi to get the details.

I'm not sure whether there's any WHOIS lookup/query provider gives JSON output at free cost.

BTW, i just found this [phpWhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) from sourceforge.net, would be a good starting point to use whois from the server. This is the library used by RoboWhois / RubyWhois provider as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use whois npm module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/whois

Also in mac terminal, try this to see whois data

whois google.com

Comment: Looks like it does not work with io domains